# additional row when last row has [wartosc] = 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table with process data containing nazwa, wartosc, czas. The table data look something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYNM4.jpg)

Now I wrote query:

```
;WITH [cteRows] AS
(
    SELECT  [nazwa],
            [wartosc],
            [czas],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [czas]) AS [RowNumber]
    FROM [test].[dbo].[coldbox7]
    WHERE [nazwa] = 'coldbox7/WymianaDanychDB/Hydraulic' 
    AND [czas] >= '2016-07-14 22:00:00.000' 
    AND [czas] <= '2016-07-14 22:30:00.000'
) 
SELECT  mc.[RowNumber],
        mc.[czas],
        mc.[nazwa],
        mc.[wartosc],
        DATEDIFF(SECOND, mc.[czas], ISNULL(mp.[czas], mc.[czas])) AS [Wsekundach]
FROM [cteRows] mc 
LEFT JOIN [cteRows] mp 
    ON mc.[RowNumber] = mp.[RowNumber] + 1 
WHERE mc.[wartosc] = 0
```

And output [look like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJH71.jpg)

I have question:

- How can I make additional row when last row has `[wartosc] = 1`?
- And than I would like to add row where: `[Wsekundach] = '2016-07-14 22:30:00.000' -(substract)'2016-07-14 22:18:26.000'`?

Comment: Is this a SQL Server or MySQL question?

Comment: I am pretty sure this is `SQL Server` because of `CTE`. I just dropped the `mysql` tag

Comment: This is MSSQL database

Answer (score 1):

This might better be done on the reading side (application logic?)...

How is this called? Inlined (`VIEW` or `UDF/TVF`) or executed (`SP`, `EXEC`, `BCP` ...).

#### If executed

You might use `SELECT ... INTO #tmpTbl FROM ...` to fill your result in a temp table first and then use `IF` to insert your last row

```
;WITH [cteRows] AS
(
    SELECT  [nazwa],
            [wartosc],
            [czas],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [czas]) AS [RowNumber]
    FROM [test].[dbo].[coldbox7]
    WHERE [nazwa] = 'coldbox7/WymianaDanychDB/Hydraulic' 
    AND [czas] >= '2016-07-14 22:00:00.000' 
    AND [czas] <= '2016-07-14 22:30:00.000'
) 
SELECT  mc.[RowNumber],
        mc.[czas],
        mc.[nazwa],
        mc.[wartosc],
        DATEDIFF(SECOND, mc.[czas], ISNULL(mp.[czas], mc.[czas])) AS [Wsekundach]
INTO #tmpTbl
FROM [cteRows] mc 
LEFT JOIN [cteRows] mp 
    ON mc.[RowNumber] = mp.[RowNumber] + 1 
WHERE mc.[wartosc] = 0;

IF (SELECT TOP 1 [wartosc] FROM #tmpTbl ORDER BY RowNumber DESC) = 1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #tmpTbl VALUES(/*Your Values here*/);
END

SELECT * FROM #tmpTbl;
```

#### If inlined

You might try to add a reversely sorted row number and use an `UNION ALL` to add a row with a `WHERE` clause checking for the reveresed number `=1` and your `wartosc=1`. Set your values as needed.

```
;WITH [cteRows] AS
(
    SELECT  [nazwa],
            [wartosc],
            [czas],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [czas] DESC) AS [RowNumberDesc],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [czas]) AS [RowNumber]
    FROM [test].[dbo].[coldbox7]
    WHERE [nazwa] = 'coldbox7/WymianaDanychDB/Hydraulic' 
    AND [czas] >= '2016-07-14 22:00:00.000' 
    AND [czas] <= '2016-07-14 22:30:00.000'
) 
SELECT  mc.[RowNumber],
        mc.[czas],
        mc.[nazwa],
        mc.[wartosc],
        DATEDIFF(SECOND, mc.[czas], ISNULL(mp.[czas], mc.[czas])) AS [Wsekundach]
FROM [cteRows] mc 
LEFT JOIN [cteRows] mp 
    ON mc.[RowNumber] = mp.[RowNumber] + 1 
WHERE mc.[wartosc] = 0 

UNION ALL

SELECT  mc.[RowNumber],
        mc.[czas], --your values here
        mc.[nazwa],
        mc.[wartosc],
        DATEDIFF(SECOND, mc.[czas], ISNULL(mp.[czas], mc.[czas])) AS [Wsekundach]
FROM [cteRows] mc 
LEFT JOIN [cteRows] mp 
    ON mc.[RowNumber] = mp.[RowNumber] + 1 
WHERE mc.[RowNumberDes]=1 AND mc.[wartosc] = 1
```

Comment: I can't add row to database, and now I have error: 
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near 'ROW_NUMBER'.

Comment: @G.Dabrowski You would not *add a row to your database*, just add a row to the tmpTable, which is thrown away after this job...

Comment: What does it mean "your values here"? What should I write hier? I want to show result on site, so I will use inlined

Comment: Now I Have error: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 33
Invalid column name 'RowNumberDes'.

Comment: @G.Dabrowski, Sure... untested code is always prone to errors... The `c` is missing (`RowNumberDesc` stands for *row number in descending order* (something you could have found yourself actually...). And for your last comment: *Your values here* means, that this `UNION ALL SELECT` will add exactly one row (or no row) to your result set. You can put any value you want to see there into the right place: e.g. `mc.[RowNumber]+1` for the next higher number, and appropriate values for `czas`, `nazwa` and `wartosc`...

Comment: @G.Dabrowski, is this question still open? Do you need further help?